# if/elif and sequencial if statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Sorry if this question is a duplicated, but as my English is not so good, I didn't figure how to formulate the question and I want to understand something about `if` and `elif` statements.

I am doing an exercise where I have to get from list `x`, the items that are not found in list `y`. This is with a method of comparing each element from both lists.

I solved it, but I didn't udnerstand the logic behind sequential `if-elif` statements for example:

My working code:

```
def merge_2(xs, ys):
    """
      Return only those items that are present in the first list,
      but not in the second.
    """
    result = []
    x_index = 0
    y_index = 0

    while True:

        if x_index >= len(xs):
            return result

        if y_index >= len(ys):
            result.extend(xs[x_index:])
            return result


        if xs[x_index] < ys[y_index]:
            result.append(xs[x_index])
            x_index += 1
        elif xs[x_index] > ys[y_index]:
            y_index += 1
        else:
            x_index += 1


print(merge_2([1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 35, 46, 54, 58, 62, 78, 82, 94], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 54, 68, 78, 82]))
```

The result is: `[3, 12, 35, 46, 58, 62, 94]`

The code that differs is:

```
def merge_2(xs, ys):
    """
      Return only those items that are present in the first list,
      but not in the second.
    """
    result = []
    x_index = 0
    y_index = 0

    while True:

        if x_index >= len(xs):
            return result

        if y_index >= len(ys):
            result.extend(xs[x_index:])
            return result


        if xs[x_index] < ys[y_index]:
            result.append(xs[x_index])
            x_index += 1
        if xs[x_index] > ys[y_index]:
            y_index += 1
        else:
            x_index += 1


print(merge_2([1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 35, 46, 54, 58, 62, 78, 82, 94], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 54, 68, 78, 82]))
```

Giving the result `[3, 12, 46, 58, 94]`

So, my question is: Why do my results differ so much if they appear to do the same thing?

Comment: `set(x)-set(y)` done

Comment: Other than that.. your problem can also be solved with 2 for loops.

Comment: Each `if` statement is *independent*. `elif` is part of an `if` statement, and Python can only ever pick *one* of the branches.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast and short answer, i am working with How to think like a computer scientist and there's an exercise with this problem. But i guess i figured out why works different, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 for explaining why. :)

Comment: So for a set of `if...elif...else` branches, Python picks the first that matches, then *ignores the rest no matter what*. If you have a series of `if`s in a row, they all are independent, and it doesn't matter what happened in earlier `if` statements (provided you didn't end the function with a `return` or jumped out of a loop with `break` or `continue`, or raised an exception, but that's something different).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! i thought it after debbuging it!, for if/elif statement it will be evaluated once per element, but for sequential if, they will be evaluated sequentially, that's why results differ, thanks for your answer!